# How do I find where a port is?

Tags: freebsd

If I want to find out which directory under /usr/ports contains a port like "gnome-terminal", how can I do that? Is there an easy command? At the moment I use things like

> echo */gnome-terminal

but is there a website or guide which tells you this without having to use a trick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways that you can find a port, including your `echo` technique.  To start, there is the [ports](http://www.freebsd.org/ports) site where you can search by name or get a full list of available ports.  You can also try:

```
whereis <program>
```

but this--like using `echo`--won't work unless you type the exact name of the port.  For example, `gnome-terminal` works fine but `postgres` returns nothing.  Another way is:

```
cd /usr/ports
make search name=<program>
```

but keep in mind that this won't return a nice list; it returns several `\n` delimited fields, so `grep` as necessary.  I've used both of the above methods in the past but nowadays I just use `find`:

```
find /usr/ports -name=<program> -print
```

Lastly, I will refer you to the [Finding Your Application](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-finding-applications.html) section of the handbook which lists these methods along with sites like [Fresh Ports](http://www.freshports.org/) which is handy for tracking updates.

Comment: Also http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?stype=all&sektion=all&query=